# Is it possible to install Gentoo portage manager (emerge) on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gentoo, repository, apt-get, portage

And vice versa? 
For example install apt-get on Gentoo and connect Ubuntu's repositories.
And if it is possible how can I do it? (at least in general terms)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be interested in [Gentoo Prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/).

> Usually, Gentoo's Portage installs in
>   the root of the filesystem hierarchy,
>   '/'. On systems other than Gentoo
>   Linux, this usually results in
>   problems, due to conflicts of software
>   packages, unless the OS is adapted
>   like Gentoo/FreeBSD. Instead, Gentoo
>   Prefix installs with an offset,
>   allowing to install in another
>   location in the filesystem hierarchy,
>   hence avoiding conflicts. Next to this
>   offset, Gentoo Prefix runs
>   unprivileged, meaning no root user or
>   rights are required to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you might be able to do. But is is going to be highly experimental and not very useful and very unlikely to teach you anything.

Comment: why is it not going to teach?

Comment: It will actually teach you a lot...